# Why does "git svn fetch" command seem to be stuck and does nothing?

Tags: git, git-svn

**EDIT: Workaround.**
Now we understand the issue, here is the solution: do

```
git svn fetch -r REVISION:HEAD
```

where REVISION is the number of the svn commit of the branch creation.

---

I've been happy using git svn to work on the trunk of my project for a while, but now I need to track branches also.

I've tried to initialize a new repository to do that with

```
git init
git svn init https://svnserver/svn/repository
```

Then I edit the local configuration file to reflect the structure of my svn repository:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://svnserver/svn/repository
    fetch = path/to/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = path/to/branches/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
```

Then I run

```
git svn fetch
```

And this command just does nothing:

- It does not terminates
- It does not write anything in the console output
- It does not use any CPU, nor create files

I gave up after 10 minutes

I've checked that the svn repository is working, because `git svn fetch` works perfectly on my git repository where I track only the trunk.

Is this a bug or am I missing something here ?

Comment: Big time saver, thanks! with -r it was almost instant, even with our svn repo that has dozens of active branches and a long history (over 20k commits).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It becomes verbose after fetching the first relevant commit.

But until it fetches that commit, you can ensure the command is working properly by checking the `.git\svn\.metadata` file. The lines `branches-maxRev = 123` and `tags-maxRev = 123` will keep updating and increasing their numbers as it works.

Comment: And it can take forever to see the "first relevant commit" so you need to be patient and go away and just leave it until you see something... Don't get bored and CTRL+C like I did! :D

Comment: Check the edit made by the OP: if you know the revision number of the "first relevant commit", you can quicken the process.

Comment: It seems to me like the process is doing nothing. I ran this on the machine where the SVN repo is located, but the CPU is not even going about 5%. It's like there's a sleep statement that just goes for 1 hour at the start of the process.

Comment: Yes it can take a lot of time... in my case more than one hour (since it is a huge repository). But important not, and maybe you have to add this! .metadata has not changed in my case for about 30 minutes...

Answer (score 16):

Try adding the `--log-window-size=5000` parameter.

If the repo has a large number of commits, git-svn will go through them `100` at a time by default. Bumping that up can increase its speed tremendously.

Answer (score 12):

In case of using Git for Windows, make sure to upgrade from 2.20.1 to either previous (2.20.0), next (2.21.0) or any other. Mentioned version has a [bug making "git svn fetch" hang](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1993), which was later fixed.

Answer (score 2):

For those who were not satisfied with the solution above :

**ISSUE :** 
svn+ssh://svn.xxxxxxx.com/svnroot/strategy/products/mysoftware
hangs on :

> Initialized empty Git repository in [MyLocalRepositoryPath]

**SOLUTION:** Insert

> username@

in front of svn url

> svn+ssh://username@svn.xxxxxxx.com/svnroot/strategy/products/mysoftware

Comment: Seems to be working for me. What's the rationale behind this?

Comment: Just in case, this tip works for processes that are actually **stuck**, as is my case. It could get stuck for hours at a time, processes almost hung. The problem as stated in the question is just git svn not being stuck but rather taking a loooong time to start writing relevant information because of starting the fetch process too early or so.

Comment: my svn username is an email address like name@company.com
The url should be like https://name@company.com@xxxx.com/path    ??

Answer (score 0):

i have change the fetch property to :refs/remotes/git-svn and it  works for me