# git svn fetch not working

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

`git svn fetch` doesn't fetch any new revisions from the remote SVN server, even though I know that my local version is out of date.

When doing `git log`, the last revision happens on the 5th of December, whereas when I type in `git svn log` the latest revision is yesterday (not mine).

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 6):

Seems like `git svn rebase` fixed it.

Comment: It would be nice to know why this worked, but it worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with v.2.20.1. Upgrade of Git solved my issue. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/54910767/2432802