# Git svn fetch does not do anything?

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to migrate a single svn branch to git. I am doing this on my Windows machine using the `git svn` command in the Windows command prompt.

I have initialized a .git repository in a local folder and run the following command:

```
git svn init https://companyname.svn.cloudforge.com/blb400
```

After this command I have the following config file in my .git folder:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    noMetadata = 1
    url = https://companyname.svn.cloudforge.com/blb400
    fetch = :refs/remotes/blb400
[svn]
    authorsfile = C:/temp/so-design/users.txt
```

Then from the command prompt I am executing the following command:

```
git svn fetch -r 103:HEAD
```

I am trying to get the latest revision from the svn branch because I suppose getting just one revision will be fast.  But the `git svn fetch` command hangs there for hours and does not do anything. No log information, nothing. I have read all the posts on Stackoverflow about this, and they all suggest that the command could be slow and therefore it should be used with the -r option, which is what I am doing. Unfortunately nothing happens?

I hava already looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878976/why-does-git-svn-fetch-command-seem-to-be-stuck-and-does-nothing/10881325) but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "git svn fetch" command seem to be stuck and does nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878976/why-does-git-svn-fetch-command-seem-to-be-stuck-and-does-nothing)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-svn%5D+fetch+hangs

Comment: Especially see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54910767/7976758

Comment: phd's comment above is the answer to my problem. Updated GIT to version 2.21.0 and it worked. Please consider adding it as an answer. Thanks man!